# Regex expression needed for "find" in files in visual studio

Tags: regex

Suppose I have

```
try
{
MyFunctionCall()
{---------------}
}
catch----------------------
```

I want to replace all those functions having a similar try block with
MyFunctionCall;the first three lines should match, by some other code in a single
shot like

```
try
{
ReplacedFunction()
{---------------}
}
catch----------------------
```

NOTE: MyFunctionCall() can be present in some code without a try block or in other calls.

Comment: What is this? Formalize your code in question.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which version of VS? (They changed their regex engine in the latest version). Can there be anything other than whitespace between the `try`, the `{` and `MyFunctionCall`?

Comment: Question now formatted. I am using visual studio 2008. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest but this works in VS *2012*...

**Find what:**

```
(try[\s\n]*\{[\s\n]*)MyFunctionCall(\(\)[\s\n]*\{(?:([^\}]|\n)*\}){2})
```

**Replace with:**

```
$1ReplacedFunction$2
```

**Visualization:**
[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/jyaxd3iCF_tmSzPw)